# How to escape special characters in a regex replace in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file which contains string like

```
<disp-formula id="deqn*"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
x=5 \tag{5}
y=3 \tag{6}
x+y=8 \tag {7}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>

<disp-formula id="deqn*"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
x+y=5 \tag{3}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>

<disp-formula id="deqn*"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
a+y=15 \tag {4a}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>

<disp-formula id="deqn*"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
x=5 \tag {9a}
y=3 \tag{10}
x+y=8 \tag{11}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>
...etc
```

I'm trying to convert them to

```
<disp-formula id="deqn5-7"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
x=5 \tag{5}
y=3 \tag{6}
x+y=8 \tag {7}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>

<disp-formula id="deqn3"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
x+y=5 \tag{3}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>

<disp-formula id="deqn4a"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
a+y=15 \tag {4a}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>

<disp-formula id="deqn9a-11"><text-notation="math">\begin{equation*}
x=5 \tag {9a}
y=3 \tag{10}
x+y=8 \tag{11}
\end{equation*}</text-notation="math"></disp-formula>
...etc
```

using a couple of regex replace on the file.
The first regex replace looks like

```
(?s)(<disp-formula id="deqn)[^"]*?("(?:.(?!/disp-formula))+?.\\tag\s?\{)([^}]+?)(\}(?:.(?!/disp-formula))+.\\tag\s?\{)([^}]+?)\}
```

which is replaced by

```
$1$3-$5$2$3$4$5}
```

and the second regex is

```
(?s)(<disp-formula id="deqn)[^"]*?("(?:.(?!/disp-formula|\\tag))+?.\\tag\s?\{)([^}]+?)(\}(?:.(?!/disp-formula|\\tag))+?</disp-formula>)
```

which will be replace by

```
$1$3$2$3$4
```

Both the regex have been tested using **http://regexstorm.net/tester** and it works but when I try to use it in my code it does not work.

I'm struggling to escape some characters in my regex I think, can anyone help me
here is my code

```
string content=File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test\00057_po.txt");
string pattern1 = "(?s)(<disp-formula id=\"deqn)[^\"]*?(\"(?:.(?!/disp-formula))+?.\\tag\\s?{{)([^}]+?)(}}(?:.(?!/disp-formula))+.\\tag\\s?{{)([^}]+?)}}";
string replacement1 = "$1$3-$5$2$3$4$5}}";
string pattern2="(?s)(<disp-formula id=\"deqn)[^\"]*?(\"(?:.(?!/disp-formula|\\tag))+?.\\tag\\s?{{)([^}]+?)(}}(?:.(?!/disp-formula|\\tag))+?</disp-formula>)";
string replacement2 = "$1$3$2$3$4";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern1);
Regex rgx2 = new Regex(pattern2);
string result1 = rgx.Replace(content, replacement1);
string result2 = rgx2.Replace(result1, replacement2);
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test\00057_po.txt",result2);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just a piece of advice: you may actually try to parse it with `XDocument` and then use XML means to grab the necessary values to build the required output. If the text contains invalid XML you may still write a parser to grab the texts between `<disp-formula` and `</disp-formula>` (ok, even a regex will do if there are no overlapping tags) and then still parse those as `XElement` and you will have the whole arsenal of XML means. BTW, `(?:.(?!/disp-formula|\\tag))+?` should actually look like `(?:(?!/disp-formula|\\tag).)+?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would love to use `XDocument` to parse it but the text contains invalid XML...BTW how do I write a parser to grab texts between `<disp-formula` and `</disp-formula>` even when the file is not a valid xml?

Comment: Adding to what Sani Singh said, providing a plunker is helpful to getting a quick working fix together..

Comment: Use `(?s)<disp-formula\s.*?</disp-formula>`

Answer (score 1):

Try these

```
    string pattern1 = "(?s)(<disp-formula id=\"deqn)[^\"]*?(\"(?:.(?!/disp-formula))+?.\\\\tag\\s?\\{)([^\\}]+?)(\\}(?:.(?!/disp-formula))+.\\\\tag\\s?\\{)([^}]+?)(?=\\})";
    string replacement1 = "$1$3-$5$2$3$4$5";

    string pattern2="(?s)(<disp-formula id=\"deqn)[^\"]*?(\"(?:.(?!/disp-formula|\\\\tag))+?.\\\\tag\\s?\\{)([^\\}]+?)(\\}(?:.(?!/disp-formula|\\\\tag))+?</disp-formula>)";
    string replacement2 = "$1$3$2$3$4";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape {} aswell like:

```
"(?+s)(<disp-formula id=\"deqn)[^\"]*?(\"(?:.(?!\\/disp-formula))+?.\\tag\\s?\\{\\{)([^\\}]+?)(\\}\\}(?:.(?!/disp-formula))+.\\tag\\s?\\{\\{)([^\\}]+?)\\}\\}";
```

Comment: @kLennartz I'm getting `Unrecognized escape sequence` on this

Comment: I checked it up and you have to escape /, too

Comment: both `\/` and `\{` get the error **Unrecognized escape sequence** and `\}` too

Comment: You have to write \\ if you want to use \ as escape sequence for regex. You always have to to escape \ if you dont use @ before your string

Comment: I'm still confused